# Transfer changes from one Git repo to another

Tags: git, bitbucket

There is a UserA and two Git repositories - repoA and repoB, UserA has write access to repoB but read access only to repoA. I have write access to both repositories. UserA commit changes to repoB and I need to transfer these changes to repoA.

Is it possible to do it in BitBucket webpage or natively in Git?

Comment: There's the notion of pull requests using bit bucket's ui

Comment: Are `repoA` and `repoB` clones of each other?

Comment: @Chris - yes, repoA and repoB should contain the same source code, userA shouldn't write his changes directly to repoA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git clone <repoA_url> -- myrepo
cd myrepo
git remote add rb <repoB_url>
git fetch rb <branch_userA_pushed_to>
git branch repob FETCH_HEAD
#assuming you are working on repoA's master
git checkout master
```

Now you could manipulate `master` and `repob`. UserA's changes(commits) are on `repob`. You could run `git rebase` or `git merge` or `git cherry-pick` to apply UserA's changes onto `master`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. One clarification please - `rb` and `repob` is the same name?

Comment: @user1315357 no, `rb` is the name of repoB's remote, like `origin`. `repob` is the name of the branch that tracks `branch_userA_pushed_to`. You could name both whatever you like.